# add a custome domain to firebase hosting

Tags: flutter, firebase, web, hosting, firebase-hosting

**i am tring to a dd acustome domain and change the email verification to it through firebase and I add the new server and show to me it is connected but when I try to open my website I found this error**
[image: site not found]